# Column name of function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I want column name of table.

So I try this

```
select * 
from sys.columns 
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnproduct()')
```

but this didn't show any data ..that's why I try using dynamics SQL.

```
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from sys.columns  
                                  where object_id=OBJECT_ID('''+dbo.fnproduct()+''')'

    print @sql

    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnproduct", or the name is ambiguous.

Help me to solve this or suggest me alternative way
and ya..I want to pass function here

Comment: which sql server version u are using

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Get the List of All Columns of a table from the System View `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Just Select

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YouTableName'
```

Note :

If you are trying to Get the List of Column Name from a Function (That's what I felt while looking at your Code) It is not possible, because Functions does not have a Column Name unless it is a Table Valued Function. In That case Use this

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.YourTVF')
```

Comment: don't think that includes UDF

Comment: Oh..so it means it doesn't need parameter. Can u please explain me why?

Comment: it's because the Object Name does not include the Parenthesis ().

Answer (score 4):

Try this query :

```
SELECT c.name [ColumnName] 
FROM sys.columns C
INNER JOIN  sys.objects O ON C.Object_id = O.Object_Id
WHERE O.NAME = 'FunctionName'
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need dynamic sql

```
select *
from   sys.columns
where  object_id = object_id('fnproduct')
```

if you need the input parameters, get it from `sys.parameters`

Comment: Oh..so it means it doesn't need parameter. Can u please explain me why?

Comment: i mean if you required to show the input parameter to your `fnproduct`, you can get it from `sys.paramters`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.name, [type] = t.name, c.max_length, c.[precision], c.scale
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
  ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
  AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
  WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('fnproduct')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`;

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SampleTable'
```

Also, I don't know what the `fnproduct()` returns but you should specify the database and table name;

```
USE SampleDatabase
select * 
from sys.columns 
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```